# Получение введённой в консоль строки

Tags: c++, консоль

Использую для получения строки с консоли

```
string command;
getline(cin, command);
```

Однако, если начать набирать строку, а в это время другой поток напишет что-то в консоль через `cout`, то начнётся полная анархия из твоей строки вперемешку с сообщением из потока.

Как можно исправить эту беду?

Comment: Засемафорить работу с консолью мьютексом...

Comment: @Harry неа. Нужно, что бы одновременно и поток писал в консоль, и я мог писать команду...

Comment: Нужно, чтобы одновременно, но не одновременно... :)

Answer (score 1):

Стандартная для C++ консоль для этого не предназначена. Как вы вообще предсавляете одновременный ввод и вывод в одной консоли? Ввод и вывод должен происходить раздельно, по принципу "ввод команды - вывод результата", или же приложение должно только выводить данные, игнорируя ввод. Если приложение выводит данные асинхронно - выводите их в файл, а не в консоль. Или реализуйте простой GUI с раздельными полями ввода и вывода. На том же Qt это легко делается. Если же вам нужно именно консольное приложение - погуглите библиотеки для GUI в консоли.